# How to get featured products REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

How to get REST API for `featured products, Best sellers and Sale products`?
Is it possible with `searchCriteria` parameter?

Comment: I do not think so, you need to create your own API to do this.

Comment: anyone help me rest api 404 error : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/246597/57334

Comment: I also want to fetch featured products and new products for my App. how to achive this using rest API?